# Templates not loading in Django

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Problem: template not loading with view ....

I've been following a django tutorial, hoping to get some templates working that I created. It looks like this.

```
app/templates
└── app
    └── profile.html
```

Settings file looks like this:

```
"""
Django settings for demonstration project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.10.3.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

TEMPLATE_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'SOME_KEY_NON_PROD_TESTING_LOCALLY'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'app',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'demonstration.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'demonstration.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

The tutorial mentioned defining a template dir so I defined:

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]
```

However, that didn't work so I also saw the DIRs option in the template stanza to I set that to the same value as TEMPLATE_DIRS that I added above.

I still don't see any change here. I am obviously missing something about the config that should point to the template but I'm stumped as to what that is at the moment.

The view:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponse
import requests
import json

# Create your views here.

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse('Hello World!')

def second_view(request):
    return HttpResponse('This is the second view!')

def profile(request):
    jsonList = []
    req = requests.get('https://api.github.com/users/<username_here>')
    jsonList.append(json.loads(req.content.decode()))
    parsedData = []
    userData = {}
    for data in jsonList:
        userData['name'] = data['name']
        userData['email'] = data['email']
        userData['public_gists'] = data['public_gists']
        userData['public_repos'] = data['public_repos']
        userData['avatar_url'] = data['avatar_url']
        userData['followers'] = data['followers']
        userData['following'] = data['following']
    parsedData.append(userData)
    return HttpResponse(parsedData)
```

The page source of localhost:8000/app/profile

```
{'followers': 1, 'public_repos': 5, 'avatar_url': 'https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/XXXXX', 'email': None, 'following': 4, 'name': None, 'public_gists': 1}
```

Comment: How is your template rendered in the view?

Comment: I assume you mean the view itself - it is just pain text (its actually just json content). The view has no css associated when it loads. - added the actual template above.

Comment: You haven't shown anything that is not working. Where is your view? What is your template? What url are you using? What problem are you having?

Comment: Also, I see that you have this `TEMPLATE_DIRS` in your config, why? you have already `TEMPLATES = [{...}]`

Comment: You still haven't said what is not working. Your views don't even use any templates.

Comment: @DanielRoseman the template does not load. The URL routing seems to be correct because the page itself loads (I've updated above without) but without the desired template / styling.

Comment: **What** template? Your views don't *use* any template.

Comment: @ettanany it was suggested in the tutorial to use TEMPLATE_DIRS which seems right as per the docs. The TEMPLATES = [{...}] was pre-existing and so I updated both. I also tried with and without both but with the same result.

Comment: I can't understand what you're asking at all. You return a raw http response containing a dict. There is no template involved anywhere.

Comment: @DanielRoseman makes sense - seems it is not in the tutorial. I assumed the association was based on the method / view name. I need to return / render to view.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your `templates` folder is in your project root folder and you have `profile.html` like this:
`templates/app/profile.html` then your view should be something like:

```
def some_view(request)
    # some code
    return render(request, 'app/profile.html')
```

Your profile view could be:

```
def profile(request)
    # your code
    return render(request, 'app/profile.html', {'data': userData})
```

Now, in your template `profile.html`, you can access the object `data`

Answer (score 0):

Need to return render to view e.g.     return render(request, 'app/profile.html', {'data': parsedData})